# Simple Word Count in C

Tags: c, file-io, word-count

I'm creating a word count function in c as part of a larger text file processing program, but I'm encountering some discrepancy in results.

Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
#define OUT 0
#define IN  1
unsigned countWords(char * filename) {

    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int state = OUT;
    int wc = 0;
    char c;

    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open file");
    }
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            printf("c: %c & wc: %d\n", c, wc);
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
        }
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++wc;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return wc;
}
```

I'm testing this function with two short .txt files:

```
word word word  word
word
```

and..

```
word word word
word
```

Note that in the second .txt, the last word is followed by 3 newline characters.

When I run these .txts through, the first file is always counted correctly with a return of 5, but the second file seems to be reading the 3 newline characters at the end of the file and increases the count to 7.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? If you are on Windows, lines will end with `\r\n`

Comment: or even better `isspace(c)`

Comment: Yeah, it was the Windows \r\n that was giving me trouble. I'm running the program on a vagrant Ubuntu virtual machine but the text files are saved on the host machine, so I think there were still \r attached. Thanks for the help everyone

EDIT: isspace() also caught the \r as well, should've just gone with that initially

Comment: Note that a file may contain non-printable characters for which isspace() is false. Also, how about punctuation marks that are surrounded by spaces? Are they considered to be words?

Comment: That's a good point FredK, I did think about that once I resolved the initial issue and have since added additional conditions to ignore punctuation marks and numeric characters when determining whether to increment the word count, also accounting for hyphenated words and the like

Answer (score 1):

Tip : if you move text file from windows to Unix system machine you can always run dos2unix command on the files and you won't need to worry about checking newline format that windows system uses.